# rewrite wordpress plugin url somthing else

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a plugin for wordpress.
I want to rewrite the plugin url.for example I have this :

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/common/user/panel.php
```

which is a panel for wordpress users to do some thing.
How can rewrite that url to this ?

```
http://www.domain.com/panel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you're purposely letting your users directly access your Wordpress plugin php file**

You can do this by using **.htaccess** file and create a rewrite rule the way you have mentioned in your question.

The basic way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^/panel.php?$ /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/common/user/panel.php [L]
```

The first parameter is the matching url and the second one is the substitute url. Also [L] means this should be the last rule nothing should follow if matched.

Here's a good article if you're new to this: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

**If not, simply catch the url request before Wordpress starts from your plugin**

I would start with this:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'panel_handler_action');

function panel_handler_action() {
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/panel.php') { //make sure /panel.php is not existing
      //do your stuff here
}
}
```